# For loop in R - error in if - missing value where TRUE/False needed

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am working on a project for personal development. I have never used R before so i am struggling a bit. 
I would like to get Longitude and Latitude based on a location. the script works fine until it gets NA value.
I have tried to use `if`, `tryCatch`, `is.na` and many other functions but nothing works.

The aim is, I get latitude and longitude based on Location. Many values are missing in this csv file. So I need something that can avoid `NA` values. Is there any other way to get there ?
Thanks

```
library(ggmap)

for(i in 1:nrow(MassShooting)){

    Data <- geocode(MassShooting$Location[i], output = "latlona", source = "google")

                MassShooting$Longitude[i] <- as.numeric(Data[1])
                MassShooting$Latitude[i] <- as.numeric(Data{2])
}
```

Here is my table(it contains around 400 rows):
[image]

Solved : Here is the code i used :

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data1))
{
    ifelse(is.na(data1$Location[i]), NA,      
    result2 <- geocode(data1$Location[i], output = "latlona", source = "google"))
          data1$Longitude[i] <- as.numeric(result2[1])
          data1$Latitude[i] <- as.numeric(result2[2])

}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Also, it is very likely that you don't need to run a for loop because R vectorizes by default.

Comment: When i run the code it get this error message :
```  
`Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Orlando&key=xxx-FtbqKmVdTh8Zwido
Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Ferguson&key=xxx-FtbqKmVdTh8Zwido
Error in if (location == "") return(return_failed_geocode(output)) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`
```
Thing is i am not using if at all, and i don't know how to avoid NA value so that the code keeps running

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `tidygeocoder` package. No need for loops:

```
library(tidygeocoder)

mydf <- tibble::tibble(location = c(NA, "Orlando, Florida", "Ferguson, Missouri"))
mydf <- geocode(mydf, location, method = "osm")
mydf
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  location             lat  long
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 NA                  NA    NA  
2 Orlando, Florida    28.5 -81.4
3 Ferguson, Missouri  38.7 -90.3
```

Comment: Thank you,
Would this work for a csv file? or it has to be a limited list ?

Comment: You would have to bring in the data from csv into R. I would advise doing so using `read_csv()` from the `readr` package. There is daily rate limit with OSM, but I don't know what it is. Probably not a big deal unless your list is in the thousands.

Comment: Actually i have already imported the csv file,  provided API key, grouped variables etc. the calculations of LanLon is the part i am struggling with. Once done i will add new values to csv file with rbind. i am downloading `TidyGeocoder` to try your code.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function `geocode` is trying to check whether the `location == ""`, but `NA == ""` returns `NA` instead of `TRUE`.

```
Data <- ifelse(is.na(MassShooting$Location[i]),
               NA,
               geocode(MassShooting$Location[i], output = "latlona", source = "google")
                       MassShooting$Longitude[i] <- as.numeric(Data[1])
                       MassShooting$Latitude[i] <- as.numeric(Data{2])
)
```

You can do the same thing with `if(){}else{}` statements.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it but it gives `Error: object Data not found` 
  Is it because it's outside the function and should be inside?